# Rails is not rendering my .js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have this code in my `create.js.erb` file:

```
pollingAJAX();

function pollingAJAX() {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/status",
        data: {uuids: '<%= @uuid_hash.to_json %>'},
        },
        success: function(data){
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(obj.isDone == "yes"){

            }else{
                obj.each(function(result) { 
                  if(result.status == "completed"){
                     $('a[href="#{result.url}"]').html('');
                  }
                });
                pollingAJAX();
            }    
        }
    });
}
```

This AJAX request is not being triggered because my create.js.erb file is not being rendered. I have this code in my `create` action:

```
result['items'].each do |r|
 # escaped_url = URI.escape(r['link'], Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]")).gsub("%","-")
  @site_array << r['link']
  if Result.where(:link => r['link']).present?
  else  
    job_id = ImageGenerator.create(:url => r['link'])
    @uuid_hash[r['link']] = job_id
  end   
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

I think it may have to do with the fact that I am processing a bunch of background jobs with Resque before calling `respond_to`?

How can I get my `create.js.erb` file to be triggered?

Comment: @Murali good point, i posted the relevant code from the action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Make sure you're actually including your JavaScript with a `<script>` tag, otherwise it will never be loaded.

Move the invocation of `pollingAJAX()` to *after* that function has been defined.  Provided it (lexically) parses ok, JavaScript executes linearly, as it's interpreted, rather than compiled and then executed, so the `pollingAJAX()` function doesn't yet exist where you've put the invocation.

Also, always view your source code in the browser, to make sure the .erb has processed the way you intended.  And make use of your JavaScript console in your browser to detect any errors.

Comment: How are you including it in your HTML?

Comment: The create.js.erb.  It doesn't just magically get into your HTML.  You need to include it with a `<script>` tag ;)

Comment: I always thought that if you have a `.js.erb` file with the same name as your action, rails automagically renders it... I'm confused :P

Comment: I've never seen that, but you could be right.  It does sound like the sort of thing Rails would try and do, but it would be a dangerous thing for it to do, since ordering can be important.

Comment: Actually, there's no way.  If it did that, your request would have to execute twice, which would have side-effects.

Comment: I'm almost 100% positive rails does this. It's what I've been doing on my other project. This case may be different though...

Comment: could you provide an example of including it?

Comment: Hmm, you could be right, I've just never needed to do that.  It would have to execute the request twice though, since JS is loaded over a separate HTTP stream to your HTML.  Does this mean you'd be creating twice the number of jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that you are using jQuery from your AJAX request syntax, you can bind your method to the DOM load event:

```
$(function() {
  pollingAJAX();
});
```

This will prevent pollingAJAX() from executing until after the entire Javascript file has been parsed, allowing this function to find its definition.

See more here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready